# Showing technical difficulties if using add_to_cart() function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have added this code for a custom checkbox product. But after clicking the checkbox and when we click the `add to cart` button then this error is showing. `The site is experiencing technical difficulties.` How can I overcome this?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'custom_product_option_checkbox_field' );
function custom_product_option_checkbox_field() {
    if (isset( $_POST['option1']) && $_POST['option1'] != '') {
        echo '<p><label><input type="checkbox" id="option1" name="option1" value="certificate" checked> '.__("Add PDF Certificate at <span>&#163;9.99</span>").'</label></p>';
    }else{
        echo '<p><label><input type="checkbox" id="option1" name="option1" value="certificate" > '.__("Add PDF Certificate at <span>&#163;9.99</span>").'</label></p>';
    }
}


add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'custome_add_to_cart');
function custome_add_to_cart() {
    global $woocommerce;
    echo $_POST['option1'];
    if ($_POST['option1']) {
            $product_id = 2218;         
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't run the code but I can see that you have one extra semicolon (;) at line 6 - this will produce a error and might be the reason your function isn't working properly.

Comment: Removed semicolon. but the problem still alive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By inserting a new product using `WC()->cart->add_to_cart` in the action `woocommerce_add_to_cart` function it creates a indefinite recursive loop which throws the error.

We can fix this by removing the `add_to_cart` action before inserting the new product:

```
remove_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', __FUNCTION__);
```

Updated code:

```
    add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'custome_add_to_cart');

    function custome_add_to_cart() {
        if (isset($_POST['option1'])) {
            $product_id = 2218;

            // Prevent the add_to_cart action from looping
            remove_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', __FUNCTION__);

            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        }
    }
```